# How to make variable size 2d arrays in R?

Tags: r, arrays, list

I would like to create a 2d array to store a known number of elements with unknown lengths of each element. However, I am not experienced with R and all the things I tried either require you to state the dimensions beforehand or don't let you append to the elements afterward. Here is something I tried:

```
b <- list(rep(c(), 5))
for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:i) {
    b[i] <- append(b[i], i)
  }
  print(b[i])
}
```

This gives this warning `Warning message in b[i] <- append(b[i], i): “number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length”` and does nothing

Here is what I wanted to achieve, but in python:

```
b = [[] for _ in range(5)]
for i in range(1,6):
  for _ in range(i):
    b[i-1].append(i)
```

I don't mind different data types, something like a dictionary will be ok, but I struggle with getting an idea of how this works in this particular case. The examples above are quite dumb, but, in short, what I want to achieve is: `[ [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1] ]` or `{ 'a': [1,2], 'b': [1,2,3] }`

What is the cleanest way to do that in R?

Comment: I think you are looking for a `list()`, which should be able to hold the information the way you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to append list you can simply add it to preexisting list.

```
b <- list()

for(i in 1:5){
  b[length(b)+1] <- list(seq(1:i))
}
```

If you want to add to an existing list you can simply use `c()`

```
b[[3]] <- c(b[3][[1]], 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that will be useful. But what if I want to change it afterward? For example, something like this: ```b[3] <- append(b[3], 1)```

Comment: @user9102437 you can use `c()` instead of `append` for adding elements to list

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you say, that you want the equivalent in R of the following code in Python,

```
b = [[] for _ in range(5)]
for i in range(1,6):
  for _ in range(i):
    b[i-1].append(i)
```

Which returns the following output:

```
[[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

I have 2 ways to do so in R.

```
num_elements = 5
```

**1st method**: *You need to load `rlist` library. Check [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlist/versions/0.4.6.1)*

```
install.packages("rlist")
library(rlist)
```

---

```
list1 <- list()
for (i in 1:num_elements) {
  list1 <- list.append(list1, rep(i,i))
}
list1
```

**2nd method**: *Predefined the initial list with a fixed size.*

```
list2 <- list(rep(NULL,num_elements))
for (i in 1:num_elements) {
  list2[i] <- list(rep(i,i))
}
list2
```

In both ways, the ***output*** would be the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 3 3

[[4]]
[1] 4 4 4 4

[[5]]
[1] 5 5 5 5 5
```

To get items as a list of the sequence of numbers, then you only have to change `rep` by `seq`, as follows:

```
list1 <- list()
for (i in 1:num_elements) {
  list1 <- list.append(list1, seq(1,i))
}
```

In this case, the output is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```